# Solution to iterative equation with floor operation

Tags: sequences-and-series, signal-processing

This question is motivated by the following signal processing problem.

Suppose there is a source, which produces vectors of data of length $N_s$, and a filter (or other subsystem) that accepts vectors of data of length $N_f$, where $N_s \neq N_f$. We require a buffer between the two blocks to deal with the overflow or collect data until there is enough to pass whole blocks to the filter of its expected size.

#### What is the minimum value for the required size of the buffer, $N_b$, such that it never overflows?

[image: System diagram]

I can write down an iterative equation for the number of samples contained in the buffer at any given time. Let $B^+$ be the number of samples in the buffer after adding $N_s$ samples from the input, and let $B^-$ be the number of samples in the buffer after removing as many multiples of $N_f$ samples as possible and passing them to the filter. Then,

$B^+_{t+1}=B^-_t + N_s$, and

$B^-_{t+1} = B^+_{t+1} - \lfloor\frac{B^+_{t+1}}{N_f}\rfloor N_f $,

where $t$ is the time step index, $B^+_0 = 0$, and $B^-_0 = 0$.

Using the above formulas I was able to confirm empirically my suspicion that the maximum value attained by $B^+$ is $\max_t(B^+_t) \leq N_f + N_s - 1$ for values of $N_s$ and $N_f$ between 1 and 2000, and for 5000000 time steps. However, I would like to know if there is an analytical solution to the above equations, or some other way of framing the problem that makes an analytical solution simple?